# Критерий выбора Spring 4 и EJB 3.*

Tags: spring, java-ee, ejb, db2

На каких критериях основывать выбор между технологиями Spring 4 и EJB 3?
Читал вот это
http://samolisov.blogspot.com/2014_12_01_archive.html
Но тут начались споры.
У меня сейчас задача написать приложение которое будет работать с данными из таблицы с которой уже работает другое приложение так, чтобы не случалась взаимная блокировка (AquisitionLock). 
Так же нужно чтобы это приложение работало с очередями IBM WS MQ. База db2, сервер приложении IBM WAS 7.0
Если я правильно понял, то в spring минус только в громоздкости библиотек?

Comment: Spring возник когда javaee была совершенно непригодно для использования. Со временем разработчики javaee одумались. Выбирают его, думаю, потому что это стандарт "из коробки", который теперь вполне годный. Так зачем тянуть ещё и spring? Имеет смысл spring брать только частями, аналогов которых нет в javaee. Например jdbctemplate, если кто-то использует jdbc напрямую.

Comment: @Sergey ну, не совсем непригодно. Применяли много и успешно. Просто требовалось немало дополнительных телодвижений для этого. С другой стороны, я пришёл в JavaEE после Ассемблера и Сей, поэтому абсолютно не понимал стонов коллег :)

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы собираетесь развернуть приложение на полноценном сервере приложений, то лучше пишите EJB. Spring лучше выбирать для небольших проектов которые будут работать на контейнере сервлетов (Tomcat, Jetty).
Если все же выберете Spring, то его библиотеки можете развернуть на WAS как Shared library.

P.S. В случае когда два приложения работаю с одними и теми же данными взаимных блокировок не будет, хотя возможны проблемы с синхронизацией данных.

Comment: На WAS не  всякое SPRING приложение "взлетит".

Answer (score 0):

Зачем Вам еще и spring если WAS имеет все возможности правильного подключения db2 и mq? Вся троица очень хорошо дружит друг с другом. WAS имеет достаточное количество инструментов для создания приложений уровня предприятия.  а для  чтения таблицы уже  используемой другим приложением,  можно правильно  настроить db2  и параметры транзакции в WAS.